# Can I enter Germany couple of days before my visa starting day?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, germany, brazilian-citizens

Recently, I was offered a PhD position in Germany starting in September. Accordingly, I applied for a visa and was granted a research stay visa valid from September 1st to February 29th. However, I was unable to book a flight ticket for August 31st, and purchased a ticket for August 28th (arriving on August 29th). I am feeling quite foolish as I hadn't considered this might be an issue until a friend pointed it out.

I am from Brazil. In theory, I could stay in Germany as a tourist for these 3 days before my visa becomes valid. Naturally, I have secured travel insurance and booked an Airbnb starting from August 29th. I am also bringing a substantial amount of money to cover my expenses during these initial weeks.

Do you believe there's a possibility that my entry could be denied under these circumstances? What steps can I take to minimize the chances of that happening?

Thank you all for your help

Comment: I did the same with Austria. I have a Salvadoran passport and arrived in Austria a few days before my D visa was valid. Had no issues.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't require, as a Brazilian citizen, a visa to enter the Schengen Area you can enter as a visitor until your research visa starts.

Comment: thank you very much